# lmer model: non-normal residual

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, normality-assumption, assumptions

I sometimes run into problems that the residuals of my lmer models are not normally distributed.
I was wondering what to do in such circumstances?

Is `gamm` (generalized additive mixed model) the non-parametric equivalent to lmer?
Or is `glmer` (generalized linear mixed-effects model) the non-parametric equivalent to lmer?

My variables are always continuous so glmer with binomial or poison families do not fit. Whenever I fit the models with Gaussian, the results tell me to go back to lmer; I also tried gamma family and it also doesn't work.

I am aware of the following questions and answers but they don't solve my problem:

- [non normal distribution in lmer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486102/non-normal-distribution-in-lmer)
- [Problem with non-normal residuals (lmer function)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441317/problem-with-non-normal-residuals-lmer-function)
- [R lmer Model Diagnosis qqnorm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125856/r-lmer-model-diagnosis-qqnorm)
- [Heavy-tailed errors in mixed-effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138759/heavy-tailed-errors-in-mixed-effects-model)

I am also aware that you can log transform the data, but it doesn't always work on my data.

Could anyone tell me which types of models I should try? Thanks!